# Elements in an Object Array are always updated according to new target events

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, addeventlistener

Hello I am trying to make a simple project where the program tracks and records the details of the `click` events from the `targets` that fires the events in `trackObject`, and then stores it in the `details` array.

However, it keeps updating the previous `trackObject` with every new click that I make. For example, when I click `Box 1`, it stores the details of the events from `Box 1` into `details`, but when I click `Box 2`, it stores also the details from `Box 2`, but also replaces the details of `Box 1`. In the end, details of `Box 2` are stored twice in `details` array.

May I please know what my mistake is here?

Thank you!

```
<html>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div> <br>
        <div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div> <br>
        <div id="box3" class="box">Box 3</div> <br>
        <div id="box4" class="box">Box 4</div> <br>
    </div>

    <script>
        let container = document.querySelector(".container");
        let details = [];
        let trackObject = {
            textContent: null,
            id: null,
            tagName: null,
            className: null
        }

        container.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            trackObject.textContent = e.target.textContent;
            trackObject.id = e.target.id;
            trackObject.tagName = e.target.tagName;
            trackObject.className = e.target.className;

            details.push(trackObject);
            console.log(details);
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let details = [];
let trackObject = {
  textContent: null,
  id: null,
  tagName: null,
  className: null
}

container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  trackObject.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  trackObject.id = e.target.id;
  trackObject.tagName = e.target.tagName;
  trackObject.className = e.target.className;

  details.push(trackObject);
  console.log(details);
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div> <br>
  <div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div> <br>
  <div id="box3" class="box">Box 3</div> <br>
  <div id="box4" class="box">Box 4</div> <br>
</div>
```

Comment: You're only defining the object once and pushing it into the array on every click. Move the object creation code within the listener callback so a new object is created on each click.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem. However, there is another unrelated problem that you might experience.

To solve the old data showing up problem, you can move your let trackObject declaration into the click handler, or set a variable within the click handler to the trackobject and just use that to overwrite each time.

The second problem that you might experience is that by adding the click handler to the container of the divs, you can get clicks on the spaces between the divs. To solve this, I'm looking for the class box on the target of the click.

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
        let details = [];
        let trackObject = {
            textContent: null,
            id: null,
            tagName: null,
            className: null
        }

        container.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
           if(e.target.className.includes("box")){
            let obj = trackObject;
            obj.textContent = e.target.textContent;
            obj.id = e.target.id;
            obj.tagName = e.target.tagName;
            obj.className = e.target.className;

            details.push(obj);
            console.log(details);
            }
        })
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div> <br>
  <div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div> <br>
  <div id="box3" class="box">Box 3</div> <br>
  <div id="box4" class="box">Box 4</div> <br>
</div>
```